# .clang-format explicit control of the format specifiers to enforce

Tags: c++, clang-format

### Use-case

Apply standard formatting across the code base

### Implementation

use .clang-format to automatically apply format standards

### Problem at hand

".calng-format" supports a large set of formatting options, however, each of the options has a default behavior/value that is always applied.
I have not found any way to explicitly set specific options to control.
**Example:**
I can't enforce curly brackets in a new line w/o enforcing eg. Tab size, or max line length, these will use the default values...

Is there a way to set a "don't care" value on .clang-format options ?
Is there a way to explicitly set those format options we would like to control ?
Is there any other equivalent tool supporting explicit format style specification ?